# Multiple counts on same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here am repeating the subquery twice,

`(select count(*) from hindi2_MOVIE as yaar where yaar.year = M.year)`, which I dont want to do, is there any way to reuse them, just by running the query only once?

I need to find the total count,say 'tot' of entry grouped by year, and then the percentage of some other feature ,where the denominator is the total count 'tot'. In the following SQL query I am repeating the select operation twice, which I know is very expensive, is there anyway to reuse the same?

```
select M.year,
     (select count(*) 
      from hindi2_MOVIE as yaar 
      where yaar.year = M.year) as tot, 
    count(M.title)/(select count(*) 
                    from hindi2_MOVIE as yaar 
                    where yaar.year = M.year)*100 as perc 
from hindi2_MOVIE AS M 
where not exists (select * 
                  from hindi2_M_CAST AS C,hindi2_PERSON AS P 
                  where C.PID=P.PID AND C.MID=M.MID AND P.Gender='M') and 
                        exists(select * 
                               from hindi2_M_CAST AS C,hindi2_PERSON AS P 
                               where C.PID=P.PID AND 
                               C.MID=M.MID and Gender='F')
group by M.year;
```

Comment: Why can't use use `tot` as the variable: `count(M.title)/tot * 100 as perc`

Comment: @SamuelCook it was giving me error.`Unknown column 'tot' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alias the query result before with "@" symbol and use it any where in the same query

```
select M.year, @tot:= (select count(*) from hindi2_MOVIE as yaar where
yaar.year = M.year),count(M.title)/(@tot)*100 as perc from hindi2_MOVIE AS M
where not exists (select * from hindi2_M_CAST AS C,hindi2_PERSON AS P where
C.PID=P.PID AND C.MID=M.MID AND P.Gender='M') and exists(select * from
hindi2_M_CAST AS C,hindi2_PERSON AS P where C.PID=P.PID AND C.MID=M.MID
and Gender='F') group by M.year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is bit confusing for me.
But I would suggest you to write the query like this. This may not work. But use the following suggestions.

Never use Count(*), use count(field);
You can evaluate the difference by your self with proper usage of inner joins.
Never use IN or Exists, use inner join or left join appropriately and conditions;

Example:

select count(M.year) as tot, count(M.title)/count(M.year) *100 as  perc
from hindi2_MOVIE M 
left join hindi2_M_CAST C  on (M.SomeField = C.someField) AND C.MID=M.MID and P.Gender='M' -- (this is for not exists)
inner join hindi2_PERSON  P on C.PID=P.PID AND C.MID=M.MID and Gender='F'
  where yaar.year = M.year and some conditions;